# Big O/ Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

This maybe a trivial/ mathematical concept that I cant seem to work my head around. So if the processing time T(n) of a certain algorithm is both Ω(n) and O(n^3), how can i prove that the T(n) is Θ(n^2) is either correct or not?

Comment: No, you can't. Because complexity isn't about recounting integer polynomial powers . It may be `Θ(n log n)` or `Θ(n^2 log n)` etc. Big-Omega and Big-O are only about estimated growing relative function, not precise things.

Answer (score 2):

Let's compare the definitions of the three symbols.

(1) Ω(n) means (for sufficiently large n): n * k1 <= T(n)

(2) O(n^3) means (for sufficiently large n): n^3 * k2 >= T(n)

(3) Θ(n^2) means (for sufficiently large n): k3 * n^2 <= T(n) <= k4 * n^2

Given (3), we can infer that T(n) is in both Ω(n) and O(n^3), because for big numbers n, n * k1 is always smaller than n^2 * k2, if we just provide k1=k2 (but also for any other combination of k1, k2). The same applies for O(n^3).

This basically means that Θ(n^2) is a stronger constraint than both Ω(n) and O(n^3).

However, the other way around does not work. If (1) and (2) hold, T(n) might be as well T(n)=n, which is obviously not in Θ(n^2). So we can not infer the strong constraint from the two weak constraints. Therefore, the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

If the O had been smaller than the Θ or if the Ω had been larger than the Θ then you could prove that it was incorrect.

[This example may help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science).